# Intellij IDEA не видит org.eclipse.jetty*

Tags: прокси, настройки

IDEA не подхватывает импорт библиотек `org.eclipse.jetty.*`

Комп стоит за прокси, прокси я прописал в настройках, но результат нулевой (тест проходит) строка типа

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
```

не ресолвится.

Просить открыть на прокси что конкретно?
Я не могу объяснить админу, чего не хватает.

Помогите советом!

Comment: А какой идеей пользуетесь?

Comment: Судя по всему Используете Community Edition - а jetty не доступно в  этой версии. Посмотрите сравнение версий на сайте джет браинс: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: МГТУ-шный преп в своих лекциях рекомендует CE и нормально подтягивает jetty. Что то Вы не то говорите. Не бывает так тут пишем а тут не пишемю Разница в моем случае что у меня рабочее место за прокси.

Comment: Та дело не в том что я говорю. Скинул Вам ссылку на сайт разработчиков ИДЕИ, так как, когда я ею пользовался, то у меня лично были с некоторыми либами проблемы. И были такие  что именно из-за того что версия СЕ не поддерживала их. У меня нет препа который может мне что-то подсказать - все гугл, книги и многократные пробы и ошибки. Если преп адекватный - я бы его помучал  вопросами.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально я бы посоветовал не привязываться к конкретной библиотеке, а посмотреть подбирает ли **IDE** в целом хоть какие нибудь библиотеки.
Хотелось бы еще знать, чем вы производите загрузку (сборщиком или вручную)? Так сказать, чтобы знать от чего отталкиваться?
Если вручную, то вам путь в `ProjectProperties-JavaBuildPath-Libraries` (**Eclipse**, но смысл тот же), т.е. смотреть видит ли ваш проект ваши библиотеки.
Имхо для сборки юзаю **мавен**, система сама подбирает либы и ложит их туда, куда нужно системе. Как его настроить на прокси можно глянуть тут:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Опыта у меня пока маловато, я разбираю курс по программированию веб сервисов.
Если ручками качать и класть в lib а затем ProjectProperties-JavaBuildPath-Libraries то идея его видит, но не все библиотеки мне понятно откуда скачивать, потому хотел все таки чтоб идея этим занялась.
Если там же но не локально а из мавена указать, то список идея показывает, но выбрав библиотеку ее не скачивает, а типа не чего качать...
Да мавен сеттинг у меня вписан

Comment: Если библиотека подтянулась мавеном или вы загрузили ее в ручную и точно знаете, что она имеется в наличии, но проект ее не видит, то нужно однозначно только проверять classpath в проекте.
Если мавен список заполнен, но не скачивает библиотеку, то проверьте наличие данной версии в мавен-репозитории, возможно она уже устарела.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился методом прессования админа. Получил полный доступ и все заработало. Админу достался лог с ошибками загрузки плагинов мавена...